# In keras, how do you pass keyword arguments to loss functions?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Example:

```
model.compile(..., loss='mean_squared_error')
```

or

```
model.compile(..., loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy)
```

but `binary_crossentropy` has an optional argument, `from_logits`.  How do I set it?  I know I could define my own new loss function with `binary_crossentropy` inside it, but is there a more direct, compact way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a class first and initialize it with `from_logits` argument (see [BinaryCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy)):

```py
binary_xentropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(..., loss=binary_xentropy)
```

Another way is to use `functools.partial`:

```py
import functools
binary_xentropy = functools.partial(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                                    from_logits=True)
model.compile(..., loss=binary_xentropy)
```